# Are GTK Callbacks called from the main thread when using gtk_main_iteration?

Tags: c++, callback, thread-safety, gtk

Normally when using GTK3 callbacks with the gtk_main() function, it is expected that callbacks maybe running in a seperate thread from your programs main thread, and therefore thread safety measures need to be taken to ensure callbacks are thread safe.

However, what if your main thread deals with gtk main events manually using gtk_main_iteration?

```
// Some processing here
while (gtk_events_pending()) {
    gtk_main_iteration();
}
// More processing here
```

In this situation, are callbacks still run in a separate thread? or are they launched from the main thread?

My program has a lot going on and if it turns out callbacks are called from the main thread in this setup, it would save me quite a bit of thread safety work.

Note: I'm working with GTK3, but I believe this applies to both GTK2 and GTK3

Comment: No, GTK+ callbacks are **never** run in a separate thread. All of GTK+ has to run on a single thread, referred to as the *main thread* because in most cases it's the same thread that `main()` itself is run on. Instead, if you have multiple threads, you *have to* make sure that all GTK+ functions are run from the main thread, using `g_idle_add()` or similar.

Comment: Yeah, that's something you tend to find the hard way!