# GtK+3.0 multithreaded application

Tags: c, gtk3, jack

here's my problem:
I'm developing a multithreaded application composed by:

- GUI thread-> GTK
- helper thread --> checking connection to JACK server
- RT thread of jack--> doing some sound-elaboration stuff

I have implemented a button widget, that only receives signals from the helper and RT thread, that modify the gui in its callback function.

So, my question is: who is modifying the GUI? the helper/RT thread or the gui thread in which i used  gtk_main() ?

Thanks for your collaboration!

edit: i added the code
   /** @file JPLowPassFilter.c
 *
 * @brief this is a simple client that implements a numeric low Frequency Pass Filter
 */

```
#include "JPLowPassFilter.h" 
jack_port_t *input_port;
jack_port_t *output_port;

jack_default_audio_sample_t tmp;
int first=1;
appData* mainData;
jack_default_audio_sample_t tmp;

/*Code for port_registration_callback */
void registrationPort(jack_port_id_t port, int reg, void *arg)
{
    return;
}

/*Code for client_registration_callback */
void registrationClient(const char* name, int reg, void *arg)
{
    return;

}
/**
 * The process callback for this JACK application is called in a
 * special realtime thread once for each audio cycle.
 * Must not block!
 */
int process (jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg)
{ 
    int i;
    float alfa=mainData->alfa;
    jack_default_audio_sample_t *in, *out;
    in = jack_port_get_buffer (input_port, nframes);
    out = jack_port_get_buffer (output_port, nframes);
    for( i=0; i<nframes; i++) {
        if(first==1){
            tmp=in[i];
            first=0;
        }
        else{
            tmp=tmp*alfa+(1.0f-alfa)*in[i];
            //tmp=tmp*(1.0f-alfa)+alfa*in[i];
        }
        out[i]=tmp;
    }
    //fprintf (stderr, ".");
    return 0;      
}

/**
 * JACK calls this shutdow_callback if the server ever shuts down or
 * decides to disconnect the client
 */
void jack_shutdown (void *arg)
{ 
    mainData->state=NOT_WORKING;
    jack_port_unregister(mainData->client,input_port);
    jack_port_unregister(mainData->client, output_port);    
    g_signal_emit_by_name (GTK_BUTTON(mainData->init),"clicked");
}

/* JACK calls this function whenever there is an xrun */
int xrun_function(void *arg)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "--XRUN OCCURRED--\n");    
}

void* threadCode(void* val)
{
    const char *client_name = CLIENT_NAME;
    const char *server_name = NULL;
    mainData=(appData*) val;
    /* if server isn't present, don't start it!*/ 
    jack_options_t options =JackNoStartServer; 
    jack_status_t status;
    do{
        /* try to open a client connection to the JACK server */
        mainData->client = jack_client_open (client_name, options, &status, server_name);
        if (mainData->client == NULL) 
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "jack_client_open() failed, "
                 "status = 0x%2.0x\n", status);
            if (status & JackServerFailed) {
                fprintf (stderr, "Unable to connect to JACK server\n");
            }
            sleep(3);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Connected to JACK server\n");
            mainData->state=INIT;
            /*  CALLBACKS*/
            jack_set_process_callback (mainData->client, process, 0);
            jack_on_shutdown (mainData->client, jack_shutdown, mainData);
            jack_set_xrun_callback(mainData->client,xrun_function, 0);  
            jack_set_port_registration_callback (mainData->client, registrationPort,NULL);
            jack_set_client_registration_callback(mainData->client, registrationClient,NULL);

            /* PORTS */
            input_port = jack_port_register (mainData->client, "input", JACK_DEFAULT_AUDIO_TYPE,JackPortIsInput, 0);
            output_port = jack_port_register (mainData->client, "output", JACK_DEFAULT_AUDIO_TYPE, JackPortIsOutput, 0);
            mainData->state=INIT;
            if ((input_port == NULL) || (output_port == NULL)) 
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "no more JACK ports available\n");
                mainData->state=NOT_WORKING;
            }
            /* STARTS */
            else if (jack_activate (mainData->client)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "cannot activate client");
                jack_port_unregister(mainData->client,input_port);
                jack_port_unregister(mainData->client, output_port); 
                mainData->state=NOT_WORKING; 
            }
            else  
            {
                fprintf (stderr, "Client ready to Run\n");
                mainData->state=WORKING;
                mainData->portsName[0]=jack_port_name(input_port);
                mainData->portsName[1]=jack_port_name(output_port);
            }
             //can be written to
                        mainData->inputList=jack_get_ports(mainData->client,NULL, NULL,JackPortIsInput);
                        //can be read from
            mainData->outputList=jack_get_ports(mainData->client,NULL, NULL,JackPortIsOutput);
            g_signal_emit_by_name (GTK_BUTTON(mainData->init),"clicked");
            while(mainData->state==WORKING)
            {
                sleep(5);
                fprintf (stderr, ".");
            }
            fprintf (stderr, "\n");
                jack_free(mainData->inputList);
            jack_free(mainData->outputList);
            mainData->outputList=NULL;
            mainData->inputList=NULL;
            jack_client_close (mainData->client);       
        }
        fprintf (stderr, "---RECONNECT---\n");
    }while(mainData->state==NOT_WORKING);
    fprintf (stderr, "Ended!\n");

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Gtk is thread aware but not thread safe. Gtk functions/methods should be called from the main thread, the one on which gtk_main/mainloop is. GLib however is thread safe with some remarks.

Comment: so i shouldn't call the signal from the other 2 threads? Still i can't understand which thread is doing what...

Comment: Yes, signals are called from the "main thread". Basically, functions/methods that are used to update the GUI must be called from the main thread. We can't help you more without a better explanation or code on your question.

Comment: following your advice i uploaded the code that emits the signal, still the interface isn't properly working, in fact sometimes it will not update correctly two combobox or just crash

Comment: _"So, my question is: who is modifying the GUI? the helper/RT thread or the gui thread in which i used gtk_main() ?"_ I'm not sure that's a question. Your wording makes it unclear what you're asking, if anything. Are you saying some mysterious modifications are occurring and asking us to psychically guess who is responsible? Or are you asking which thread you should use to modify things deliberately? There does not seem to be any question or problem statement here that I can discern.

Comment: @Gionata Benelli those `g_signal_emit_by_name` from the thread are part of the problem. You must have another way to pass the information from the thread to the main thread. I'll look into it...

Comment: @underscore_d maybe i wasn't clear enough, i was asking if the signal_callback were executed by the working thread or the GUI thread, the main one, even if the signal is emitted by another  thread.

Comment: Not sure but I think unless you use `g_idle_add()` then the signal emission occurs in the thread doing the emission, and therefore that signal's handlers might be called from there too.

Comment: I think this may effectively be a duplicate of [Are GTK Callbacks called from the main thread when using gtk_main_iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551986/are-gtk-callbacks-called-from-the-main-thread-when-using-gtk-main-iteration)

Comment: @José Fonte since the data i need to exchange goes only in one way, should i make the gtk_list_store associated with each combo box global and directly modify that?

Comment: @GionataBenelli No, don't use Gtk functions on the threads. A simple way, since it's basically one way, could be the use of GLib [AsyncQueue](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html) but before that i'm trying to understand the need. Why you need to "simulate" the clicked signal on the button?

Comment: @José Fonte well i wanted to separate the gui from the sound processing, so i thought to use that signaling mechanism to have some sort of asynch callback. The function i'm calling its just updating the gtk_list_store of 2 combobox, which shows the jack_ports accessible from my client. the list of ports name (char**) is stored inside the appData structure

Comment: @GionataBenelli ok, i think i understand. You want to update the UI when the state of jack ports change. You must separate concerns, workers should not update the UI but inform the main thread which will update accordingly. An answer would be to pass an async_queue which would push data and a g_iddle_add would try a pop from the queue, if there is some data then "parse it" and change the UI. Or simply provide status methods that the main thread can pool to update the UI.

Comment: @JoséFonte, so if i get this clear: i should send some data in this async queue and then pop it from this g_idle_add and modify my UI, it's correct?

Comment: @GionataBenelli Yes, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comments, a suggestion would be to exchange the `g_signal_emit_by_name` functions for `g_async_queue_*` functions.

Let suppose that `mainData->init` points to a [GAsyncQueue](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html) created in the main thread instead of the actual button.

Then you could use on your thread:

```
g_async_queue_push(G_ASYNC_QUEUE(mainData->init), data);
```

Data can contain a simple flag to indicate the status and/or status change

Then on your main thread, when you setup the UI, you could add the idle handler with:

```
my_queue = g_async_queue_new();
...
g_idle_add ((GSourceFunc) check_async_queue, my_queue);
```

and your `check_async_queue` could be something like this:

```
gboolean check_async_queue (gpointer user_data) {
   gpointer queue_data;

   queue_data = g_async_queue_try_pop (G_ASYNC_QUEUE(user_data));

   if (queue_data != NULL) {
      // We have data, do something with 'queue_data'
      // and update GUI

   } else {
      // no data, probably do nothing

   }

   return TRUE; // can be G_SOURCE_CONTINUE instead of TRUE
}
```

The return value will indicate if the `check_async_queue` function should keep running or not, so you can have a condition to remove the function.

This will allow you to have a simple one way message queue that you can use to pass information from the worker thread to the main thread.